# Bad request 400 sending image as base64 or blob to MS Face Api, Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, api, face

I have trying to send my image base64 encode or as a Blob, or bufferArray to my Microsoft Face Api in order to get my age. Im always getting Bad Request 400 error: image is to small or invalid image format. Im using ngx webcam to generate my image base64 after taking a picture with my webcam.

I know that I can send it as a URL, uploading my image first, then sending the correct url of it, but I want to try sending the image in local storage as a binary data.

I have tried sending my image data a base64: 9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…V5LjZGO/vU70eVWYKZCynsT6ihzRj5ONxb7QqMp4Z8n9H/9k=

And as a image data url : data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD…V5LjZGO/vU70eVWYKZCynsT6ihzRj5ONxb7QqMp4Z8n9H/9k=

And as a Blob: Uint8Array(58373) [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 6, 5, 6, 9, 8, 10, 10, 9, 8, 9, 9, 10, 12, 15, 12, 10, 11, 14, 11, 9, 9, 13, 17, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 17, 16, 10, 12, 18, 19, 18, 16, 19, 15, 16, 16, 16, 255, 219, 0, 67, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, …]

but any of it has success with the response.

### App.component.ts

(my ngx webcam library helps me to generate an image as a base64 or data url, from my webcam: the variable where I store my image data is "webcamImage" )

```
/* I will not write the functions that helps ngx webcam do with it function,
*/

/* this function is in where I send my variable with the image data as base64
*/

getPersonAge( ){

    this.data.getPersonAge(this.webcamImage.imageasBase64).subscribe((data: 
       string) =>{
      this.persona = data;
      console.log(this.persona);
    })
  }
```

### data.service.ts

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient){    }

 public url =  
'https://eastus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect? 
 returnFaceAttributes=age,gender';

getPersonAge(imageUrl : any){

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':  'application/octet-stream',
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
           'processData': 'false'
        }) }


      return this.http.post(this.url,{ data:imageUrl}, httpOptions)


 }
```

What is the correct format of an image in order to send it correctly to MS Face Api, without using url image alternative.

Comment: Any answer to this? I have the same problem but I use a different api